# Regexp, matching a word multiple times

Tags: javascript, regex

This baffles me, though i suppose the problem is quite simple.

Given this piece of code:

```
var text   = ' url("https://") repeat scroll 0% 0%, url("https://") repeat scroll 0% 0%, url("https://") repeat scroll 0% 0% red';
var result = /(url)/.exec(text);
```

i get a result of `["url", "url"]` ..where i would expect `["url", "url", "url"]`

Any explanation why it's only catching 2 instances of url instead of 3

Thanks

---

**Update for accepted answer**

Actually this is part of a Modernizr function i'm rewriting for HeadJS, so the final function will be:

```
function multiplebgs() {
    var ele   = document.createElement('div');
    var style = ele.style;

    style.cssText = 'background:url(https://),url(https://),red url(https://)';

    // If the UA supports multiple backgrounds, there should be three occurrences
    // of the string "url(" in the return value for elemStyle.background
    var result = (style.background || "").match(/url/g);

    return Object.prototype.toString.call( result ) === '[object Array]' && result.length === 3;
}
```

And `console.log(multiplebgs());` will now correctly return true on supported browsers.

If anyone sees additional problems with this, please leave a comment, thanks!

Comment: You're misinterpreting the return value of `RegExp.exec()`. Read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) (particularly the "Return value" section).

Comment: @ajp15243 ah that now makes more sense ! ``The returned array has the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each capturing parenthesis``

Comment: Yup :). You probably want [`String.match(RegExp)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), as the existing answers indicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `match` with regular expression with `g` flag:

```
var text   = ' url("https://") repeat scroll 0% 0%, url("https://") repeat scroll 0% 0%, url("https://") repeat scroll 0% 0% red';
var result = (text || "").match(/url/g);
result // => ["url", "url", "url"]
```

Comment: the problem is that "text" can be null or undefined. still don't get it why it manages to match 2 instances, and not 3 ..since there are 3 in that string

Comment: @Robert See my comment on your question. Check what `.exec()` returns if you remove the `( )` from your regex.

Comment: ok, match will do fine, just need to change it to: ``(text || "").match(/url/g)`` since text can be null/undefined and that would throw an error

Comment: @falsetru Accepted, and updated my question with the actual use/case i was trying to solve. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make your regex global and use `match` instead. You also do not need the capturing group.

```
var result = text.match(/url/g);
```

`exec` when used with the global flag will also allow you to get all matches, however `exec` is much more useful when you have multiple capturing groups. In your case to get all the matches with exec, you would have to do something like:

```
var matches = [],
    urlRx = /url/g,
    match;

while (match = urlRx.exec(text)) {
    matches.push(match[0]);
}

console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

The second line is equivalent to your situation :

```
'url url url'.match(/url/)    // ["url"]
'url url url'.match(/(url)/)  // ["url", "url"]
'url url url'.match(/url/g)   // ["url", "url", "url"]
'url url url'.match(/(url)/g) // ["url", "url", "url"] same as previous line
```

Considering `/(url)/`, what's inside parentheses is equivalent to a "sub regex" which is called a subpattern, or a group. Each group is captured the same way than the entire pattern, except when using the global flag (`//g`). In this case, groups are ignored and the entire pattern is captured as many times as it is found in the text. This example will be more explicit :

```
'hello world!hello world!'.match(/hello (world)(!)/)
// ["hello world!", "world", "!"]
// [entire pattern, group 1, group 2]

'hello world!hello world!'.match(/hello (world)(!)/g)
// ["hello world!", "hello world!"]
// [entire pattern, entire pattern]
```

Check this great resource about regular expressions in javascript : http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev.shtml